# myNodeList.item(0).getNodeValue() doesn't return any value. android

Tags: android, nodelist

I have this xml file, and I have obtained a `NodeList` that contains all the models, when i call `myNodeList.getLength()`, it gives me the correct number 2. but when I call `myNodeList.item(0).getNodeValue()` which supposed to return the `url1`, it doesnt show any value. whats the problem??

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <results>
     <object id="1">
        <title>back parking lot</title>
         <assets3d>
          <model>
             url1
          </model>
          <model>
             url2 
          </model>
         </assets3d>
    </object>
   </results>
```

Parser class, I use `NodeList models = myParser.getValue(e, "model",0);` to get the models

```
public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         Log.d("child.getNodeValue() ", "child.getNodeValue() "+child.getNodeValue());
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "0000";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);    
            Log.d("this.getElementValue(n.item(0))", "this.getElementValue(n.item(0)) "+this.getElementValue(n.item(0)));
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }

     public NodeList getValue(Element item, String str,int a) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);    
            Log.d("item.getElementsByTagName", "item.getElementsByTagName "+ n.getLength());
            //return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
            return n;
        }
}


}
```

Comment: How do you put xml content into the nodelist ?

Comment: I have added the parser class

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
myNodeList.item(0).getTextContent()
```

or

```
myNodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue()
```

The "url1" is a child node of model node.

Comment: It really works on my computer. The dom xml tree is a little different from your imagination. Write a loop to output all node in console to understand the structure.